# WD element Harddrive is not being read

Tags: hard-drive, dmesg, lsusb

lsusb shows drive as listed but it is not showing in file browser.
Following is the output of dmesg :

```
[  835.749084] usb 1-3: new high-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[  835.918956] usb 1-3: New USB device found, idVendor=1058, idProduct=10b8
[  835.918963] usb 1-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=5
[  835.918968] usb 1-3: Product: Elements 10B8
[  835.918973] usb 1-3: Manufacturer: Western Digital
[  835.918977] usb 1-3: SerialNumber: 5758423145363537454E3956
[  835.919758] usb-storage 1-3:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  835.920154] scsi host2: usb-storage 1-3:1.0
[  836.940370] scsi 2:0:0:0: Direct-Access     WD       Elements 10B8    1012 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[  836.941181] sd 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[  836.941973] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Spinning up disk...
[  837.969717] .
[  838.991693] .
[  840.017744] .
[  841.043560] .
[  859.497385] .
[  860.522376] .
[  892.073541] usb 1-3: reset high-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[  892.222568] ready
[  924.837012] usb 1-3: reset high-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[ 1105.031280] sd 2:0:0:0: timing out command, waited 180s
[ 1285.075288] sd 2:0:0:0: timing out command, waited 180s
[ 1285.075325] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 1285.075332] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[ 1285.075340] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] ASC=0x44 <<vendor>>ASCQ=0x81 
[ 1285.075348] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] 0 512-byte logical blocks: (0 B/0 B)
[ 1285.075352] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] 0-byte physical blocks
[ 1464.995763] sd 2:0:0:0: timing out command, waited 180s
[ 1464.995801] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Test WP failed, assume Write Enabled
[ 1645.004226] sd 2:0:0:0: timing out command, waited 180s
[ 1645.004243] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Asking for cache data failed
[ 1645.004246] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 1645.008476] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Unit Not Ready
[ 1645.008479] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[ 1645.008482] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] ASC=0x44 <<vendor>>ASCQ=0x81 
[ 1825.026602] sd 2:0:0:0: timing out command, waited 180s
[ 2005.038891] sd 2:0:0:0: timing out command, waited 180s
[ 2005.039330] sd 2:0:0:0: timing out command, waited 30s
```

Comment: Looks like a hardware problem - the electronics components work, but the actual disk doesn't rotate, or doesn't get up to speed in 180 seconds. Do you have the reciept? OR, is your USB port underpowered?

Comment: updated the dmesg logs. Seems like some find of hardware issue.

Comment: Do you power the disk via USB ? Try to use an external power-supply or an USB hup with power-supply. If this doesn't work, the disk might be broken.

Answer (score 0):

Given that this shows up multiple times in your log data...

```
[ 1285.075332] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense Key : Hardware Error [current]
```

... I'd surmise that this is a problem with the hard drive itself.  It either doesn't power up properly, or the disk doesn't start spinning quickly enough, or the USB port is underpowered.

In either case, test this drive on a different computer.  If it still doesn't work, then the drive itself is having an issue, and that is beyond our ability to really help assist with the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For me the fix is to connect the WD Elements to a Windows machine. Then "disconnect safely" there. Then reinsert into Ubuntu. Now the device gets recognized. I read somewhere that WD Elements has some .exe installed that causes this misbehaviour but since it's my backup HD I could not format it yet to confirm. (neither could I find any .exe using nautilus)